# How can I restrict a css to particular column in datatable which has drag and drop

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to left align a specific column in datatable which has string and right align a column which has integer value.

Apart from this, I am able to do it by targeting a particular column like below:

```
.mytable tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(5) {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

But I have drag and drop functionality implemented to columns in my datatable, So when I do that the css will be there for that particular column (if the column is moved from 6th to 3rd column the css should also move to 3rd column)

Can anyone help how can I restrict that css to only that column?

Comment: Hi, can you add a class on your TD?

Comment: Yes i can use 'sClass' and aTarget as the combination,it worked but that will be applied to that column only, if i move that column then it wont apply

Comment: So, if the column 5 have class "my-column", when you move it at position 2, then the new column 2 (original column 5) doesn't have class "my-column"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`columns.className`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) option to assign class name to a column. If you're using ColReorder extension, class name moves with the column if it's dragged and dropped.

For example, see below how class `col-name` is assigned to the first column.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   colReorder: true,
   columnDefs: [
      {
         targets: 0,
         className: 'col-name'
      }
   ]
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/55a6j9vw/) for code and demonstration.